# Checkbox not loading properly in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 4 and I am learning through the docs from angular.io.

When I am trying to add a checkbox to a Dynamic Form, the form is not being loaded.

This is the link to my code - [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njjkhr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion.service.ts)

I have added 2 Check box groups and 1 Radio button group, but only the first check box group is loading and rest of the elements are not loading.

Comment: I forked the stackblitz and fixed the code as per Alexander's answer (which should be marked correct). You can see it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njjkhr-gsjd7e?file=src/app/dynamic-form-question.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the [formControlName]="question.key" to the input tag and not to the div element. **You can see the error with the Chrome WebDeveloperTools: No value accessor for form control with name: 'flightRules'.**

```
<div [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" >
  <span *ngFor="let opt of question.options">
    <label>
      <input [type]="question.controlType" [value]="opt.value" [formControlName]="question.key">
      {{opt.value}}
    </label>
  </span>
</div>

<div [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
  <span *ngFor="let opt of question.options">
    <label>
      <input [type]="question.controlType" [value]="opt.value" [formControlName]="question.key">
      {{opt.value}}
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

See the forked link: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njjkhr-4sg5nf)

Comment: @alexander..thanks for the information..based on the console log error how did you conclude that the change was in the formcontrol (this will help in my future debugging pursoses)..

Comment: I have read that error somewhere in the past. FYI: You can use formControlName only on directives which implement ControlValueAccessor (see [link](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor))